# Cannot get typed Instance of class from OSGI bundle

Tags: java, osgi

I have the following situation.I need an instance of class A in my application, and this class A comes from Bundle B (osgi) and is located in package X in that Bundle.
What i have done so far:
I have  added the bundle B to local maven repository and added it to my pom as dependency with 'provided' scope.
I have also added the package X from Bundle B where class A is residing to my pom with Dynamic-import in my pom.xml.
One thing to note here - the package X is NOT exported from Bundle B, but i know it can still work, i've seen colleagues do it , but i am not that good yet.

Anyway how i am trying to get instance of the class below :

```
Bundle bundle;
Class<?> checkClass=bundle.loadClass("full path to class A");

TypeOfClassA newClass=checkClass.newInstance();
```

and here i am getting :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException ClassA not found by myapplication
at
```

org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1532)
        at

org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:75)

But why ? I have the jar loaded, i am using the bundle classloader, also if i cast checkClass to Object, i can see the methods and fields of Class A , so looks good, how can i get an instance of class A ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OSGi there is a difference between compile time and runtime. At compile time you see the  classes of your own jar and all dependencies from maven.

At runtime a bundle by default only sees its own classes. Any other packages need an Import-Package statement in the Manifest. Normally this is automatically created by bnd when you use a class. Whenever possible you should rely on that automatism.

Your case is different of course as the package you want to access is not exported by bundle B. In this case there is no way to reach class A via the bundle classloader of your own bundle.

Instead you need to use the bundle classloader of bundle B. You can get bundle B for example from the BundleContext. Then you can load the class.

Another option is that you use an exported class C from Bundle B and use the classloader of class C to load class A.

In any case this is a hack. You should avoid to use private classes of another bundle.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for the answer.I tried to use the Bundle classloader, and i am able to get the Class<?> .The problem is that again i cannot cast to class A, lets call it PluginA class.If i go PluginA test=(PluginA)glassloader.loadclass(PluginA).newInstance, it again throws ClassNotFound

Comment: So you used the bundle where class A resides to load the class?

Comment: Hi Christian , yes exactly

Comment: thanks everybody for the help, it wasnt as trivial as i thought it will be , but one can always learn new things

Answer (score 2):

When you write something like
`PluginA test=(PluginA) classloader.loadclass("PluginA").newInstance()`
then you need to actually import the PluginA class, which, as Christian mentioned, is only possible if it is exported from the bundle it resides in. The following should work:

```
Object test= classloader.loadclass("PluginA").newInstance()
```

You will then need to use reflections to access methods of the class, etc.

Comment: Yes , this is right, it turned out that it will only work if i use reflection with InvokationHandler and  Proxy.newProxyInstance , thanks